# Recognizing a specific objects collision in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been trying to figure out how to detect collision to make a simple combat system, but the commands aren't returning what I want them too. What I'm using right now (in the unity engine):

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class swordDetect : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision CollisionInfo)
    {
        if (CollisionInfo.gameObject.name == "swordCollide")
        {
            Debug.Log("it work again");
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't returning anything, and its attached to a rock that I've been using to test it.

The `swordCollide` object is attached to the players sword, but nothing happens when it collides with the rock.

Comment: You will probably get more responses if you also tag with your programming language.

Comment: @Nick I actually don't think so. This question is very Unity specific and an additional `c#` tag might not really help. Anyway the prefered (and in latest Unity versions **only** supported) language is `c#` so i don't think it would atract more poeple's attention than the `Unity3d` tag does currently.

Comment: is `swordCollide` the only object with a `Collider`? otherwise you might get the parent object or another object in `CollisionInfo.gameObject`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Gameobject has a collider on it, which is not set to Trigger (because then it can't receive collision, but will only trigger). I would always rather tag my Gameobjects and check for the tag than for the name, because it is less error prone. If the colliding Gameobject is a Trigger, you need to check

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){}
```

Best watch the Unity tutorials about collision https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders?playlist=17120
and check the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html

Both are easy to understand and go with some sample code